# AttributeError Shows while import tensorflow, keras and pandas

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, theano

I use jupyter notebook to implement python for tensorflow, theano, and keras. Originally it works well while there're only installing tensorflow and keras, but it shows AttributeError after I install theano. While I try to use TensorFlow backend, it shows as attached pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you install? I am sure you did not use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/anaconda-overview), which is highly recommended. Use it, and the error will disappear. Also, uninstall your current setup before installing, so you don't have conflicts. This is especially recommended if you are using Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will try to uninstall all the setups I have now. But I do use anaconda as environment. The error happened right after I install Theano.

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16536) is of help.

Comment: More specifically [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16322).

Comment: Thank you all. The problem fixed. It seems like Tensorflow and Theano cannot be existing at the same time.